# Port Forwarding on Amazon EC2 Security Group doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, portforwarding

I have been trying to open port 7777 with udp protocol for the game SCP: Secret Laboratory for days. But when I go into the security group and add the rule (Same thing on Network ACLs) it doesn't work. Do you know a method to solve?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPMk3.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuu5l.jpg)

Comment: Is your instance publicly reachable at all - to what source do you open the port? What specifically does not work?

Comment: show the rules.

Comment: It has a public ip address that I can connect to via ssh but when I launch the game SCP: SL and try to connect it doesn't work even though I have opened port 7777 / udp from the Security Group and also from the Network ACLs

Comment: @corradonardone Check if a process is actually running on the said port?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma No it is not used

Comment: Exactly. You need to start the process on the machine which will listen on port 7777 and foreign address 0.0.0.0